# android AChartEngine: One bar with different color

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am using the AChartEngine library to draw bar charts. What I need is for all bars to be in one color and only one bar to be in a different color.
What I have tried is having two XYSeries with one containing 0's.
This displays a gap between the bars as follows:
[image]

Could someone please tell me how do I achieve a continuous sequence of bars with just one with a different color?

Comment: if you want to try custom bar chart then take a look at this [answer](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I modified the source code to finally achieve this.
I modified the draw method of XYChart. I added colors for each bar. I found out which bar is in the center of the screen and added a different color for it.
The 'drawSeries' method in BarChart also has to be modified to set the paint color for the lines.

Comment: can you please show some code or explain in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Bar chart using achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405858/bar-chart-using-achartengine) thread. If this does not help check [Different color bars using multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439976/different-color-bars-using-multiple-series/15464307) . I managed to do the same using the concept used by the asker in  second question. In addition I made

```
renderer.setBarSpacing(0);
```