# Achartengine : Bar graph coloring

Tags: android, achartengine

I have designed a bar graph using AChartEngine lirary::

it looks as shown below:

[image: 2]

my question is ???
 - **can i make different height  bars to have different colors(passed data is single series)**

Answer (score 0):

Check [Bar chart using achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405858/bar-chart-using-achartengine) thread. If this does not help check [Different color bars using multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439976/different-color-bars-using-multiple-series/15464307) . I managed to do the same using the concept used by the asker in  second question. In addition I made

```
renderer.setBarSpacing(0);
```

I know you've mentioned that data is passed in single series. however this is currently not implemented in AChartEngine. Lets wait for new version of it.

Comment: i need to use different color for single series , anyway ll try ur first option and see if it works..