# Singleseries bar displaying multiple colors on the basis of given data in a Barchart uding achartengine lib

Tags: android, achartengine

I am developing a Bar chart using achartengine lib, It has two single series.In which one series should show the same color always and other series show different colors as per the given values

E.g.:

<200 green color,200> x < 300 blue color >300 orange color

The code is below:`

```
public class ChartActivity extends Activity {
private String[] mMonth = new String[] {
                "Jan", "Feb" , "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                "Jul", "Aug" , "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
            };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);

            Button btnChart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chart);

            // Defining click event listener for the button btn_chart
            OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Draw the Income vs Expense Chart
                    openChart();
                }


            };
            btnChart.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        }

        private void openChart(){
            int[] x = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
            int[] income = { 25,50,75,100,125,150,175};
            int[] expense = {50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225 };



            // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
            XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
            // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense
            XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Expense");
            // Adding data to Income and Expense Series


            for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                incomeSeries.add(i,income[i]);

                expenseSeries.add(i,expense[i]);
            }

            // Creating a dataset to hold each series
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            // Adding Income Series to the dataset
            dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);

            // Adding Expense Series to dataset
            dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);


            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);


            incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
            expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
            multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
            multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income vs Expense Chart");
            multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2012");
            multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
            multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
            multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
            multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
            multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
            for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
                multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
            }

            // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
            // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
            // should be same
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

            // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
            Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

            // Start Activity
            startActivity(intent);

        }`
```

for that I have developed the code written below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different colors for single series(or elements of same series) is not yet implemented or provided by the Achartengine library... :

But there are methods using multiple series or Stacked bar graph

Check [Bar chart using achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405858/bar-chart-using-achartengine) thread. and  [Different color bars using multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439976/different-color-bars-using-multiple-series/15464307) .

**UPDATE:**
For stacke bar graph

suppose ur input data for which u want to use different color

```
   int[] expense = {50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225 };
```

declare different series as array list

```
  static ArrayList<Integer> series1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static ArrayList<Integer> series2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static ArrayList<Integer> series3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

now check data from input and add it to appropriate series

```
for(int i=0;i<expense.lenght;i++)
 { 
  if(expense[i]> 50 & expense[i]<100)
   { series1.add(expense[i]);
     series2.add(0);
    series3.add(0);}

if(expense[i]> 100 & expense[i]<150)
 {.......}
}
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, I have been through those links before,

Comment: can you suggest me some more links...?

Comment: I want to implement single series bar with different color on the basis of the values as i explained above....

Comment: tat is not possible... even i had tat issue so i instead used stacked bar graph, u can try tat

Comment: Using stacked , can you implement single series with multiple colors??

Comment: no in that u need to make different series for different range value.. each data value u check and pass it to particular series and other series with zero. tomorrow  will share some sample code how to do tat k

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, actually if u could provide me some sample code in a while instead of tomorrow actually, i need to submit this tom,Please help if possible

Comment: Hey,Can you tell me how to add different colors to them?