# Achartengine bar chart x labels not aligned correctly under the columns

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

[image]

I have this code

```
public class BarChartBuilder extends SherlockFragment implements Serializable {

    @InjectView(R.id.chart)
    LinearLayout chartContainer;
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset ChartDataSeries;
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer DataRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    private GraphicalView ChartView;
    public Chart chart;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View parent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xy_chart, null);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, parent);
        String[] titles = chart.categories.toArray(new String[0]);
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        DataRenderer = buildBarRenderer(chart.values.size());

        DataRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        DataRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(18);
        DataRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(12);
        DataRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(18);
        DataRenderer.setBarWidth(18);
        DataRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        DataRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        DataRenderer.setYLabels(0);
        DataRenderer.setOrientation(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        double max = getMaxValue();
        setChartSettings(DataRenderer, "", chart.metadata.xAxis.labels.get(0),
                chart.metadata.yAxis.labels.get(0),
                0.0, chart.values.size() + 2,
                0.0, max + Math.round(max / 2),
                Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
        DataRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
        DataRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        int length = DataRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) DataRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        }

        for (Double value : chart.values) {
            values.add(new double[]{value});
        }
        ChartDataSeries = buildBarDataSet(titles, values);
        prepareChartView();
        ChartView.repaint();
        ChartView.toString();
        return parent;
    }

    private double getMaxValue() {
        double max = 0;
        for (Double d : chart.values) {

            if (d > max) {
                max = d;
            }

        }
        return max;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("current_series", ChartDataSeries);
        outState.putSerializable("current_renderer", DataRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //    ChartDataSeries = (CategorySeries) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("current_series");
            //  DataRenderer = (DefaultRenderer) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("current_renderer");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ChartView == null) {

            prepareChartView();
        } else {
            ChartView.repaint();
        }
    }

    private void prepareChartView() {
        ChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getActivity(), ChartDataSeries, DataRenderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
        DataRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        ChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = ChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No chart element selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                   /* for (int i = 0; i < ChartDataSeries.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        DataRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setHighlighted(i == seriesSelection.getPointIndex());
                    }*/
                    ChartView.repaint();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Chart data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " selected"
                                    + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        chartContainer.addView(ChartView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        menu.clear();
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.user_profile, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataSet(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            DataRenderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, titles[i]);
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("");
            double[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add((i + 1), v[k]);
            }

            dataSet.addSeries(series);
        }
        return dataSet;
    }


    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int size) {

        int[] colors = new int[]{Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN, Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED};
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();

            r.setColor(colors[i % colors.length]);
            r.setChartValuesTextSize(24);
            r.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
    }


    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
                                    String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
                                    int labelsColor) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
    }

}
```

I think the problem is in this part

```
  DataRenderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, titles[i]);
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("");
            double[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add((i + 1), v[k]);
            }
```

but I am using i+1 for x part for the label and for the column , why are the lablels not appearing correctly aligned under their columns ?

Comment: note item3 is correct one

Comment: why using multiple XYSeriesRenderer ? what is ur requirement ?

Comment: my requirement is making a bar-chart as above photo , I will receive data as Label- value pairs and I want to display it as the above photo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with help of the following answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772824/1327384

I handled it by setting the Type from Type.Default to Type.Stacked in the getBarChartView.

```
ChartFactory.getBarChartView(TestSevenDay1.this, dataset, multiRenderer, Type.STACKED);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asdad, null);
    chartContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    dataRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    dataRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE); // does not support transparent
    dataRenderer.setBarSpacing(2);
    dataRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    dataRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    // dataRenderer.addYTextLabel(1, "Average");
    // dataRenderer.addYTextLabel(2, "Maximum");
    dataRenderer = buildBarRenderer(1);
    dataRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    dataRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    dataRenderer.setXAxisMax(5);
    dataRenderer.setBarWidth(18);
    dataRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    dataRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Item1");
    dataRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Item2");
    dataRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Item3");
    dataRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Item4");

    String[] titles = { "Title1", "Title2", "Title3" };
    chartDataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("agsa");
    series.add(1, 23);
    series.add(2, 21);
    series.add(3, 22);
    series.add(4, 25);
    chartDataSet.addSeries(series);

    chartView = ChartFactory
            .getBarChartView(getActivity(), chartDataSet, dataRenderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
    chartContainer.addView(chartView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    chartView.repaint();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is working , but what about the coloring , who can I do it ?, I want a different color for every column

Comment: I gave you the points because your answer is similar of the right one, however I found the answer in another place :)