# Achartengine - different Bar Color for BarChart in android

Tags: android, achartengine

I have created one graph in android using [AchartEngine](http://achartengine.org) library.
I want to display every Bar with different color.
What can i do, please give me some suggestion..?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can u post the sample working code?. I am also looking to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405858/bar-chart-using-achartengine). In this he is giving different color to only one bar.

Take idea of it and try to make it custom according to your requirements.