# how can I show multiple colors in a single bar in bar chart Android?

Tags: android, bar-chart

I am creating chart application in android.I am trying to make a bar chart that contains single bar.In bar chart I need different colors for particular data for single bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look [This Tutorial](http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.com/2013/07/bar-chart-in-android-using-achartengine.html) first and then for different colors you need to look up at these:

- [Achartengine - different Bar Color for BarChart in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631408/achartengine-different-bar-color-for-barchart-in-android)
- [Different color bars using multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439976/different-color-bars-using-multiple-series/15464307)